# Laravel database select method issue with spaces in table name?

Tags: php, sql-server, database, laravel

I'm attempting to query a remote database connection via the DB class, and am having issues passing a parameter as table name.

This works and returns expected results:

```
$result = DB::connection('remote')->select('select * from "Users who can post batch"');
```

However, these statements do not:

```
// $view->name returns; string(34) "Users who can post batch"
$result = DB::connection('remote')->select('select * from ?', array( $view->name ));
$result = DB::connection('remote')->select('select * from "?"', array( $view->name ));
$result = DB::connection('remote')->select('select * from [?]', array( $view->name ));
$result = DB::connection('remote')->select('select * ' . $view->name );
```

I receive this error:

```
SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 102 General SQL Server error: Check messages from the SQL Server  
[102] (severity 15) [(null)] (SQL: select * from ?) (Bindings: array ( 0 => 'Users who can post batch', ))
```

What am I doing wrong?

### Resources

Laravel database documentation:
http://laravel.com/docs/database

Comment: Have you tried wrapping the ? in square brackets []?

Comment: Just gave square brackets a whirl and those don't work either. Adding error to description...

Comment: $result = DB::connection('remote')->select('select * '.$view->name);

Comment: Someone named a table `Users who can post batch`? First you need to take away their keyboard before they do any more harm...

Comment: Haha, yes. Its a SQL view, from a remote db. Nothing I can do :-(

Comment: Do you need to escape your parameter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DB::rawThis is how you would add more parameters

```
$result = DB::connection('remote')->select(DB::raw('select * from "' . $view->name . '" where id = ?', array(1)'));
```

Answer (score 0):

You got your answer from a page which is not telling you everything. Don't use queries in plain text directy. Normally you should try to use QueryBuilder to create your queries, but, of course, if it's not possible, at least use DB::raw() to create them:

```
$result = DB::connection('remote')->select(DB::raw('select * from "' . $view->name . '"'));
```

Laravel will escape your queries to prevent sql injection.

Using parameters, the correct version I see for your is something you already tried:

```
$result = DB::connection('remote')->select(DB::raw('select * from "?"'), array($view->name));
```

But, with SQL Server, things doesn't work exactly how we think they should. So, take a look a your server logs, you might find the source of the problem there:

```
SELECT t.[text]
FROM sys.dm_exec_cached_plans AS p
CROSS APPLY sys.dm_exec_sql_text(p.plan_handle) AS t
WHERE t.[text] LIKE N'%something unique about your query%';
```

Comment: Thanks Antonio. If needed to pass an array of parameters to that statement, how would I do so? This doesn't work:

    $result = DB::connection('remote')->select(DB::raw('select * from ?'), array($view->name));